# How to make a 'wavy' border for a Linear layout in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

This question is about mobile app UI design, I've searched the web for long time for this question and didn't found any satisfying explanation - so i decided to bring it here. I'm using Android studio (Java), I have a navigation bar that is made of a `LinearLayout` that contains 5 navigation buttons in it inside my `activity_home.xml`, I want to make kind of a rounded 'wavy' border in the middle (not corners) of that navigation bar. something that will look like this:

[image]

I will share here some code and images of what i already have and what i want it to be.

**Code:**

activity_home.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/navigation_bar_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="@drawable/notifications_icon"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="@drawable/add_icon"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

navigation_bar_border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/light_dark_color"
                android:endColor="@color/light_dark_color"
                android:angle="90"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

What i have now:

[image]

What i want to achieve:

[image]

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, that can be achieved by using [BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment). How? Let's see.

First, create a function like this which returns a MaterialShapeDrawable which you can set to the `LinearLayout` as:

```
//Suppressing a Restricted API warning as it's a part of Stock Material Libraries.
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun returnBottomEdgeShapeDrawable(): MaterialShapeDrawable {

    //This is how you get the curve, the main ingredient.
    //BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment() takes three parameters:
    //FabMargin - Margin between Fab Button and the curve
    //RoundedCornerRadius - Radius to make the corners round
    //CradleVerticalOffset - Vertical offset of curve and Fab
    val bottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment = BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment(
        2f, 8f, 2f
    )

    //Diameter of the curve, current as Default Fab 56Dp
    bottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment.fabDiameter = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.56dp)

    //This is further the shape of the LinearLayout.
    //Set Corners to 0 in your case else corners of the LinearLayout will be curved
    val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCornerSizes(0f)
        //Including the main ingredient here
        .setTopEdge(bottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment)
        .build()

    //Returning the ShapeDrawable
    return MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel)
}
```

This is exact code from one of my projects. Now, use it for your LinearLayout as:

```
ViewCompat.setBackground(yourLinearLayout, returnBottomEdgeShapeDrawable())
```

Remember to give the `LinearLayout` a `BackgroundTint` as the above code will make the shape but in Black color.

I've commented the code to make it more understandable.

Edit: One tip, you can use it for other Views as well like ImageView and also, you can show the curve in other sides as well like left or on bottom, just use `setBottomEdge()` instead of `setTopEdge()`. Also, this is the exact curve you've shown aboe in the images as this is the default code of Material App Bar shared by the one of the core developers of Material Libraries, Gabriele Mariotti.